# Who picks a card name first for Null Chamber?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The card [Null Chamber](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bNull%20Chamber%5d) states

> As Null Chamber enters the battlefield, you and an opponent each choose a card name other than a basic land card name.
>
> Spells with the chosen names can’t be cast and lands with the chosen names can’t be played.

For political reasons, it's relevant to me who picks the card name first (betrayals and such).

**When casting Null Chamber, in what order do me and the chosen opponent name cards?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The active player chooses first, followed by each other player in turn order**

This is covered by the general rule of APNAP - active player, non-active player. The active player (the player whose turn it is) is the one to make choices first, followed by the other players in turn order. Another example of this rule coming into play would be any card that says "each player sacrifices a creature" - players choose sequentially in turn order, starting with whoever's turn it is, and then  after everyone has made their choice, all the chosen creatures get sacrificed simultaneously.

> 101.4. If multiple players would make choices and/or take actions at the same time, the active player (the player whose turn it is) makes
>   any choices required, then the next player in turn order (usually the
>   player seated to the active player’s left) makes any choices required,
>   followed by the remaining nonactive players in turn order. Then the
>   actions happen simultaneously. This rule is often referred to as the
>   “Active Player, Nonactive Player (APNAP) order” rule.